# Laravel new [project] not working despite PHP, Composer, everything working

Tags: terminal, homebrew, php

I'm trying to install laravel, but keep getting the "The Zip PHP extension is not installed. Please install it and try again." warning.

Here's the thing: I've installed php7.3, entering 'composer' into the terminal works, and the composer is in PATH (at least, it shows up when I enter `echo $PATH`). Also, just entering `laravel` shows me what I should expect to see when Laravel is installed (ex. it says the 'new' keyword is available to me to make a new Laravel application).

I just have no idea where I'm going wrong, and I've been on this for nearly 2.5 hrs now. Any help would be **greatly** appreciated!

(Note: anything in bold font emphasized by me)

*What my terminal looks like:*

```
--:~ $ 
Laravel Installer 1.3.3

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help            Display this help message
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Available commands:
  help  Displays help for a command
  list  Lists commands
  new   Create a new Laravel application.

Adityas-MacBook-Air:~ adityaiyengar$ laravel new AdPro

In NewCommand.php line 42:

        .      .

new [--dev] [--5.2] [--] [<name>]

Adityas-MacBook-Air:~ aditya$ brew install php@7.3
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
jenkins

: @. ..     --
To reinstall 7.3.17, run `brew reinstall php@7.3`

Adityas-MacBook-Air:~ aditya$ laravel new project

In NewCommand.php line 42:

  The Zip PHP extension is not installed. Please install it and try again.  

new [--dev] [--5.2] [--] [<name>]

Adityas-MacBook-Air:~ aditya$ echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/aditya/./vendor/bin
```

Comment: It's a bit tricky to richen text in a code block...Why do you want the first line of the code block (`--:~ $ `) in bold font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install php@7.3 with brew it won't be symlinked to /usr/local/bin. Then the system's php still is in charge. Check this with `which php`!. The system's php misses the zip module. Check this with `php -m`.

To enable brew's php@7.3 add to your current PATH (probably in ~/.zshrc, ~/.zprofile or ~/.bash_profile):

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin:....
```

Relaunch the Terminal and check for the proper php bin with `which php` (should be `/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin/php`) and whether `php -m` lists the php zip module.

Then enter `laravel new AdPro` again.

Result:

```
user@host ~ % laravel new AdPro
Crafting application...
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 92 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing doctrine/inflector (1.3.1): Downloading (100%)         
...
...
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: facade/ignition
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: fruitcake/laravel-cors
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Package manifest generated successfully.
Application ready! Build something amazing.
```